# How to create a linear gradient with 45 degrees in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I can not understand how to operate in degrees LinearGradient. I have the following code:

```
Container(
        height: 100.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
          gradient: LinearGradient(begin: FractionalOffset.topLeft, end: FractionalOffset.bottomRight, colors: [
            Color(0xFF148535),
            Color(0xFF148535),
            Color(0XFF0D6630),
            Color(0XFF0D6630),
            Color(0xFF148535),
            Color(0xFF148535),
          ], stops: [
            0.0,
            0.3,
            0.3,
            0.7,
            0.7,
            1.0
          ]),
        ),
      );
```

But `.topLeft` and '.bottomRight' don't do that is required. Picture that is below shows what I want to get. (The picture has a offset and it doesn't fit to [0.0, 0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0] because this is just example)

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try using these values:

```
 LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment(-1.0, -2.0),
          end: Alignment(1.0, 2.0),
```

Or event better

```
   LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment(-1.0, -4.0),
          end: Alignment(1.0, 4.0),
```

Y: parameter description

> The distance fraction in the vertical direction.
>   A value of -1.0 corresponds to the topmost edge. A value of 1.0
>   corresponds to the bottommost edge. Values are not limited to that
>   range;
>   /// values less than -1.0 represent positions above the top,
>   and values  /// greater than 1.0 represent positions below the
>   bottom.

Comment: How could one go about animating the begin and end values to achieve a rotating gradient effect?

Comment: why 45degree is    begin: Alignment(-1.0, -4.0),
          end: Alignment(1.0, 4.0),

Answer (score 52):

This might help you determine the angle

eg :

```
LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment(-1.0, -1),
          end: Alignment(-1.0, 1),
```

[image: Alignment in Flutter]

More Details on Gradients: [How to improve your Flutter application with gradient designs by Varun Chilukuri](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-improve-your-flutter-application-with-gradient-designs-63180ba96124)

Answer (score 25):

To anyone coming here for the answer, the proper way to do this would be with a `transform` on the linear gradient, like so:

```dart
LinearGradient(
  begin: Alignment(-1.0, 0.0),
  end: Alignment(1.0, 0.0),
  colors: [],
  stops: [],
  transform: GradientRotation(math.pi / 4),
),
```

What we're doing here is drawing a **vertical** gradient (from `-1.0` to `1.0` on the X axis) and **rotating it by 45 degrees** (`pi/4`) to create the illusion of a diagonal gradient.

Using `Alignment` can result in different diagonals when you have differently sized objects. (You can test this for yourself by applying the same gradient on two different boxes - one portrait and one landscape.)

Using `transform` always results with the same gradient, no matter the dimensions of the object.

---

*Don't forget to import the math library:*

```dart
import 'dart:math' as math;
```

Comment: This is actual correct answer. I wanted to pass angle directly. Not really wanting to calculate sine/cosine projections myself.

Answer (score 10):

Use `Alignment.topLeft` and `Alignment.bottomRight`

```
LinearGradient(
      colors: [Colors.cyanAccent, Colors.amberAccent],
      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
      tileMode: TileMode.clamp),
```

Answer (score 7):

As an option to triple7's answer, you can use a radian value instead of pi expression:

```
LinearGradient(
  begin: Alignment(-1.0, 0.0),
  end: Alignment(1.0, 0.0),
  transform: GradientRotation(0.7853982),
),
```

No need for `dart:math` in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Example CSS:

```css
background: linear-gradient(20deg, #ff0000 20%, #000000 60%);
```

With [GradientRotation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/GradientRotation-class.html):

```dart
Container(
   height: 300,
   width: 300,
   decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
         begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
         end: Alignment.topCenter,
         colors: [
            Color(0xFFFF0000),
            Color(0xFF000000),
         ],
         stops: [0.2, 0.6],
         transform: GradientRotation(20 * pi / 180),
     ),
   ),
);
```

With manual calculate [Aligment](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/Alignment-class.html):

```dart
Alignment getGradientRotate(num degree) {
  degree -= 90;
  final x = cos(degree * pi / 180);
  final y = sin(degree * pi / 180);
  final xAbs = x.abs();
  final yAbs = y.abs();

  if ((0.0 < xAbs && xAbs < 1.0) || (0.0 < yAbs && yAbs < 1.0)) {
    final magnification = (1 / xAbs) < (1 / yAbs) ? (1 / xAbs) : (1 / yAbs);
    return Alignment(x, y) * magnification;
  } else {
    return Alignment(x, y);
  }
}
```

then use:

```dart
Container(
   height: 300,
   width: 300,
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
         begin: -getGradientRotate(20),
         end: getGradientRotate(20),
         colors: const [
            Color(0xFFFF0000),
            Color(0xFF000000),
          ],
         stops: const [0.2, 0.6],
     ),
   ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use gradient by angles, It's better to use [SweepGradient](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/SweepGradient-class.html). You can play with **center**, **startAngle**, and **endAngle**. Here is the solution something that you are looking for:

```
BoxDecoration(
        gradient: SweepGradient(
          center: AlignmentDirectional(1, -1),
          startAngle: 1.7,
          endAngle: 3
          ,
          colors: const <Color>[
            Color(0xFF148535),
            Color(0xFF148535),
            Color(0XFF0D6630),
            Color(0XFF0D6630),
            Color(0xFF148535),
            Color(0xFF148535),              ],
          stops: const <double>[0.0,0.3,0.3,0.7,0.7,1.0]),),
```

Here is a very simple **example** for everyone else who wants to understand and play with **Gradient** and **Angles**:

```
 Container(
      height: 400,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: SweepGradient(
          center: FractionalOffset.topRight,
          startAngle: 2,
          endAngle: 5
          ,
          colors: const <Color>[
            Colors.red, // blue
            Colors.blue 
          ],
          stops: const <double>[0.0, 0.5],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: This is not a linear gradient. Even running your example clearly shows it as incorrect and not what the question asks.