# How can I convert CSS LinearGradient to Flutter LinearGradient?

Tags: flutter

I need to convert CSS LinearGradient to Flutter LinearGradient Here is the CSS code:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(134deg, #d6dcf4 0%, #ffffff 100%);
```

Here is my Flutter code:

```
gradient: LinearGradient(
      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
      colors: [ Color(0x0ffd6dcf4).withOpacity(0),
                Colors.white.withOpacity(1),
              ],
              stops: [
              0.3,
              1
              ])
```

How does this should look on Flutter ?

Comment: post your flutter code, what have you done so far?

Comment: What problem do you have.

Comment: @SagarAcharya How should I implement "134deg" on stops and begin,end methods ?

Comment: @UmutArpat can you share the screenshot of design that you want to create ?

Comment: @TheAlphamerc You can try with this screenshot and with this CSS code:

`background: linear-gradient(93.75deg, #4D8CC2 -5.17%, #AB33B0 109.64%);`

Preview: https://imgur.com/a/A8c5kSY

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's fairly simple , in flutter we can shave off other attributes of CSS.-

**CSS Code -**

```
background: linear-gradient(93.75deg, #4D8CC2 -5.17%, #AB33B0 109.64%);
```

---

## Flutter

For **rotation**, we can alter the properties of `begin` & `end` in `Linear Gradient`. The `begin` will indicate where the gradient of `color1` starts & `end` indicates the end of `color1` gradient.

You can determine the angle using -
[image]

*For your desired output, I obtained similar results at*

```
begin: Alignment(-1,-1),
end: Alignment(1.7,0),
```

**Flutter Code-**

Just add the color codes -

```
 return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment(-1,-1),
                end: Alignment(1.7,0),
                colors: [Color(0xffab33b0),Color(0xff4d8cc2)]
                )
            ),
        height: 1000,
     )
```

---

**Here's the Flutter output-**

Try Tweaking `x & y coordinates` in `LinearGradient`to obtain your desired results

[DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/e84f2dd17a58563164cef026a8c59c6f?null_safety=true) Check DartPad Online

[image: CSS To Flutter Linear Gradient]

Comment: Creating a LinearGradient with the right colors is not the problem, the problem is the handling of the `stop` property to create the exact same effect and have the same rotation.

Comment: Hey! For rotations do check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53488064/how-to-create-a-linear-gradient-with-45-degrees-in-flutter)

Comment: Let me know if you have any more questions

Comment: Hey! Are you still facing the difficulty ?

Comment: Hi, yes I am still facing the issue. because I can't have the same result from my preview.

The `begin` and `end` are not correct, and I can't find a way to convert the CSS to Flutter with the same exact output

Comment: @BLKKKBVSIK can you please explain in what specific "attribute" are you facing problem? You'll definitely have to do some math in order to get proper rotation degree in Flutter

Comment: The goal is to have the exact same result as this Figma preview:
https://imgur.com/a/gmEK3fM

The actual CSS is: `background: linear-gradient(150.67deg, #4D8CC2 -14.7%, #AB33B0 81.9%);`

Comment: @BLKKKBVSIK hi , were you able to convert it properly? Btw I really like your profile, just checked it out on your website :)

Comment: I still wasn't able to have the exact same result as my Figma preview, here's my code so far:

```
LinearGradient(
                        transform: GradientRotation(2.62968758),
                        begin: Alignment.centerRight,
                        end: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        stops: [-.147, .819],
                        colors: <Color>[kVitalBlue, kVitalPurple],
                      ),
```

Comment: @BLKKKBVSIK Did you check out the post above which I tagged for rotations?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234149/discussion-between-blkkkbvsik-and-anirudh).

Comment: @BLKKKBVSIK Edited the answer for future reference!