# How to Convert CSS Gradient to Flutter Gradient

Tags: css, flutter, linear-gradients

How to convert CSS Gradient

```css
background: linear-gradient(177.82deg, rgba(138, 160, 55, 0.2) 51.9%, #8E9B5E 69.3%);
```

to Flutter Gradient?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63966409/how-can-i-convert-css-lineargradient-to-flutter-lineargradient

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert CSS LinearGradient to Flutter LinearGradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63966409/how-can-i-convert-css-lineargradient-to-flutter-lineargradient)

Comment: thanks. That alone not helped me but I somehow understood

Answer (score 1):

you just need to know :

1. the hex colors of the Gradient
2. the direction (like at my example it's from top to bottom and to say it to Flutter, it'll be from topCenter bottomCenter)

see the code example:

```
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              colors: [
                Colors.red.withOpacity(0.1),
                Colors.green.withOpacity(0.8),
              ],
            ),
         ),
       )
```

[image]

**Note number 1:**
that I just used the red and the green to make it clear for you, but you can use the hex colors like that

- convert just the hashtag to 0xff like:

> #8E9B5E

to

> 0xff8E9B5E

and you can replace:

> Colors.red.withOpacity(0.1),

to be like:

> Color(0xff8E9B5E),

**Note number 3:**
the function of .withOpacity(0.1) is just for Opacity like the percentage of the color appearance (from 0.0 to 1.0) and you can change the value of the Opacity or delete it if you want and use just Colors.red or Color(0xff8E9B5E)